# Django,AttributeError at /login/ Exception Value:'MyUser' object has no attribute 'POST'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

view.py

```
def login(request):
    username = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    print(request.POST['email'])
    print(request.POST['password'])
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if (user is not None):
        if user.is_active():
            login(user)
            # messages.success(request,'Добро пожаловать %S'% username)
            return redirect('/profile')
    else:
        print("Поля заполнены неправильно")
        # messages.error(request,'Неверный пароль или почта')
        return redirect('/singn_in')
```

models.py

```
class AcountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self,email,password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have a valid email adress.')
        account=self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )
        account.set_password(password)
        account.save(using=self._db)
        return account

def create_superuser(self,email,password):
    account=self.create_user(email,password=password)
    account.is_admin= True
    account.save(using=self._db)
    return account


class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='Пользователи'
    email=EmailField(unique=True,db_index=True)
    username=CharField(max_length=130,blank=True)
    balance=IntegerField(null=True)
    is_admin = BooleanField(default=False)
    #is_active = BooleanField(default=True)

USERNAME_FIELD='email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
objects =AcountManager()

@property
def is_superuser(self):
    return self.is_admin

@property
def is_staff(self):
     return self.is_admin


def is_active(self):
    return True

def has_perm(self,perm,obj=None):
    return True

def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
    return True


def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email


def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email


def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
    return self.email
```

login.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign in</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    #centerLayer {
        width: 400px; /* Ширина слоя в пикселах */
        margin: 0 auto; /* Отступ слева и справа */
        background: #fc0; /* Цвет фона */
    }
   </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="centerLayer">
        <h1>Sign in</h1>
        <form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail *">
            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Пароль *">
            <button type="submit">Enter</button>
         </form>
        <h3><a href="{% url 'registration' %}">Or regisration</a></h3>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ситуация такая, происходит вход на страницу аутентификации пользователя.Введеные данные успешно проходят:

```
if (user is not None):
    if user.is_active():
        login(user)
```

но в login(user)---->username = request.POST['email'] выдает ошибку что у моей модели нету метода Пост.Прошу помощи обьяснить или натолкнуть на выход с положения.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, ваша собственная функция называется login и системная функция называется так же. Будет конфликт. Либо переименуйте свою функцию, либо импортируйте системную под другим именем. Во-вторых, функция [login()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login) принимает два параметра, первый из которых - `request`.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login

def login(request):
    username = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active():
            auth_login(request, user)
    ...
```